# How to validate custom user information on Firebase Authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

**Context**

I'm using Firebase phone authentication. and i have one mobile app for users and one web app for admin.
both users are stored in one collection.

**Requirement**

Now I want to validate that user is a admin when  a user try to login in Web Application.
I keep data with users that "isAdmin" like this...

```
users:[
 {
   name:'John Doe', 
   phoneNumber:'+911234567890', 
   isAdmin:true
 } ]
```

Now I want to validate every web authentication that user is an admin. otherwise i want deny the authentication,

Language: Javascript

Comment: "I keep data with users that "isAdmin" like this" => **Where** do you keep this data? I a Firestore dataabse?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec maybe he want to use [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) which will help him to validate user

Comment: @Ashish Yes, this is what I had in mind but, before proposing him this approach, I wanted to understand where is the `isAdmin` property set. The idea was to emphasized, in an answer, the advantages & drawbacks of a solution based on a field in Firestore, compared to Custom Claims (e.g.: easier to modify by end users -no need to use the Admin SDK-, extra Firestore read, ...).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec that's one way to use authentication

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I keep it in firestore

Answer (score 3):

Since the user's role is stored in a user document in a Firestore collection (named `users` if I correctly understand), when the user is signed-in (and therefore you have the user's uid and phone number) you should query the `users` Firestore collection to get his/her role (`isAdmin` true or false).

Then based on the role, you can either display the content of the Admin app or show an error and sign-out the user (you cannot "deny the authentication" but you can sign-out the user after he/she signs-in).

**HOWEVER, the most important is to secure your database (and other Firebase backend services, if you use them) with some Security Rules based on the role.** If your backend is secured, a non-authorized user who succeeds in opening or reverse-engineering your Admin frontend app can maybe see the GUI elements but cannot read and modify the corresponding data.

Since you store the role in a Firestore document, you need to use, in your Security Rules, the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) function, in order to get the contents of the user document. See the example in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

---

Having said that, another classical approach to set up a role-based access-right strategy is to use [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), as explained by @Ashish in his answer.

One main advantage of using a Custom Claim is that the role (the claim) is contained by the ID token and therefore no additional lookup to a Firestore doc is needed to check for admin permissions.

You should note that you can only set Custom Claims from a privileged server environment by using the Firebase Admin SDK. This means via a server you own or via a Cloud Function (see this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e), for example). You could also use the new dedicated ["experimental" extension](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/experimental-extensions/tree/next/firestore-auth-claims).

Setting the roles through a Firebase doc, as you do, is easier (just a document write or update), **but you need to correctly secure the collection, in order to avoid a malicious user can modify a user doc.**

Another advantage of Custom Claims is that they can be used **in the Security Rules of all the services** (Firestore, Cloud Storage, RTDB). With role declaration via a Firestore doc, you should note that you cannot get this role in a Cloud Storage or RTDB Security Rule (you cannot read Firestore from Security Rules of the other services).